# How to apply same method to different types in Go?

Tags: go

How to apply same method to different types without repeating code in Go ? I have type1 and type2 and want to apply method Do()

```
type type1 struct {  }
type type2 struct {  }
```

I have to repeat code , see below. Go has static typing, so type has to be determined during compile time.

```
func (p type1) Do() {   }
func (p type2) Do() {   }
```

This works fine ..but I don't like repeating code

```
type1.Do()
type2.Do()
```

Comment: If there is some commonality between the types that you would want to use in your `Do` function, you can encapsulate that in an interface and define `Do` on that interface. If you provide some more information about your types and function, I or someone else can give you a concrete example.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear how the logic goes here, but one common pattern in Go is encapsulating the shared functionality in another struct type and then embed it in your type:

```
type sharedFunctionality struct{}

func (*sharedFunctionality) Do() {}

type type1 struct{ sharedFunctionality }
type type2 struct{ sharedFunctionality }
```

Now you can call `Do()` on `type1` and `type2` instances or in any other type that you need this functionality.

**Edit:** based on your comment, you can just redefine some equivalent types such as `t1` and `t2` that follow the desired protocol (having a `Do()` method) like this:

```
func main() {
    var j job

    j = new(t1)
    j.Do()

    j = new(t2)
    j.Do()
}

type job interface {
    Do()
}

type t1 another.Type1

func (*t1) Do() {}

type t2 yetanother.Type2

func (*t2) Do() {}
```

Here the types `another.Type1` and `yetanother.Type2` are not defined by you. But you can do whatever the logic demands with `t1` and `t2` - as far as public members go, or if you are willing to mess with that reflection thing :)

Comment: thnx, but I don't like to look for shared fields. These structs of type 1 and type 2 are not created by myself, pretty long and complex. I would rather repeat code ;)

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get in Go is to have one type embed another.

```
type Type1 struct {}

func (t *Type1) Do() {
   // ...
}

type Type2 struct {
    *Type1
}
```

The only limitation with this is that your `Do()` function will only have access to the fields of Type1.

Comment: I will definitely try this one asap, looks like closet to what I want and maybe I will be fine with access only to the fields of Type1

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use interface here. Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type testInterface interface {
    Do()
}

type type1 struct{}
type type2 struct{}

func (t type1) Do() {
    fmt.Println("Do type 1")
}

func (t type2) Do() {
    fmt.Println("Do type 2")
}

func TestFunc(t testInterface) {
    t.Do()
}

func main() {
    var a type1
    var b type2

    TestFunc(a)
    TestFunc(b)

}
```

Comment: Thnx, I tried it too, but it still doesn't fix repeating the code because in fact "Do type 1" is the same as "Do type 2"